# A jar contains 5 balls numbered: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Tags: probability

**What is the sample space when trying to pick three balls out of the five in the jar?
Using the sample space, find the probability that:

a) one of the balls is "4"

b) one of the balls will *not* be "4"

c) "1" and "5" will be picked

d) "1" *or* "5" will be picked

Afterwards, repeat a), b), c), and d) without using your sample space, but through selection instead.**

---

For me, I guessed that the sample space would be five since there are five balls in total.

As for the answers, I'm not too sure. I got:

a) $\frac 45$

b) $\frac 15$, because there is only a small chance that you will miss getting a 4.

c) $\frac 25$

d) $\frac 35$

This is as far as I got, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The sample space in your case would be $$\Omega = \{ (a_1,\: a_2,\: a_3)\:\:| \:\: 1 \le a_i \le 5 \wedge a_i \neq a_j \}$$ where triples, actually, inordered. So the total number of elements in $\Omega$ is ${{5}\choose{3}} = 10$.

1. To count the probability that one of the balls is "4" you have to count the number of triples $(a_1,\: a_2,\: a_3)$ where one of $a_i$ equils 4. It is exactly ${{4}\choose{2}} = 6$, which means $$ {\sf P}(\text{one of the balls is "4"}) = \frac{6}{10} = \frac{3}{5}$$
2. Use the fact that ${\sf P} (A) = 1 - {\sf P} (\bar{A})$
3. Quite similar to 1.
4. $$ {\sf P} (\text{1 or 5 is in triple }) = 1 - {\sf P}(\text{1 and 5 not in triple})$$

Comment: Good answer. In case it's unclear to inotomy6, the $\binom{4}{2}$ comes from the fact that assuming you have selected the ball "4", there are 4 remaining balls and we must choose 2 of them. Which can be done in $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ unique ways.